# How to remove single Word from response

Tags: c#, json, string, replace

I have one of the filed from json file its changing randomly .. if getting from value with datetime i need to replace T with space("")
field  from:2021-10-07**T**10:04:07
Expecting result  from:2021-10-07 10:04:07

Comment: Just use tryparse here if(DateTime.TryParseExact([your string here],"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) {  replace the T }

Comment: You have to show your json if you need some real help

Answer (score 0):

C# has a built in Replace method for string and char data types. If you are only removing a single character from a string 'T' I suggest using the char '' Replace method vs. the string "". But either should work.

If the Json result always contains a T in the DateTime you are parsing then the following should work:

```
// note to make sure you replace with a space between your ' ' as '' will simply remove the T 
// and there will be no space between the Date and Time in the string.
nameOfJsonVariable.Replace('T', ' ');
```

Otherwise something like what Yeronimo commented will be necessary to check if the T is in the string or not before replacing it.